# See you~What does it mean?

Tags: grammaticality

What does see you means?
Is it bidding goodbye or saying that I am coming soon to meet u...means I am on my way to meet u?
Does it has two meanings?

Comment: "See you" is pidgin English. There is evidence that it is a transliteration from a variety of non-tense languages in Asia in the mid-20th century or earlier. There is more influence from Asian pidgin on the English language than linguists would like to admit. There is no denying that Asian pidgin has been influencing US and Europe gradually. How could it be denied that presence of immigrants could not significantly alter the language styles of their host countries?

Comment: I couldn't quite keep a straight face reading this, @BlessedGeek.  Are you kidding us?  "See you!" is lazy person speech for "I'll see you later!"  Pidgin English indeed!  I won't deny that immigrants affect the language, but not this time.

Answer (score 6):

As a stock phrase "See ya!" does in fact mean "Goodbye!"

Variations include "Be seeing you" and "See you again soon. " It is a warmly connoted bidding of farewell.

It is related to *Auf Weidersehen*- literally "until (I/we) see (you/each other) again"

I suppose one could also see it as short for "I see you," a game one plays with a baby (peek-a-boo) but the farewell is by far the more common case.

Comment: Likewise 'au revoir'.

Comment: Many other languages have some form of "See you (later)". I think the 'later' just gets dropped here

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous statements made when departing that include phrases that suggest the parties will meet again. This is a form of expressing a bond with someone who is more than a stranger. The speaker is indicating that she *wants* to see the other person another time.

The example you offer, *See you*, means

> I hope [or intend] to see you on another occasion.

Many other similar departure statements (which can be made by the person leaving, the person being left or both) include

> - until we meet again
> - be seeing you
> - until next time
> - au revoir
> - auf wiedersehen
> - later
> - goodbye for now
> - ta ta for now

Many of the words in such statements may be replaced by colloquial or slang variants, such as *ya* for *you*, *bye* for *goodbye*, and *'til* for *until*.